# Gradle Could not expand ZIP: is not a ZIP archive

Tags: gradle, zip

I am trying to unzip an archive file in my Gradle build script.

The archive file exists, and I have checked that it is indeed a zip file by running

```
file myfile.zip
```

However, build fails with the following error:

> Could not expand ZIP '/.../file.zip': is not a ZIP archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason this can happen is if the file is damaged or corrupted.

The way to check that is to try manually unzipping the file.

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows:**
Please delete the package of the zip file and clean gradle. It will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was semi-unrelated. My build directory was owned by root and I was running as a user that did not have permissions to write there. I ended up deleting the dir and the next gradle build handled it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. it was due to permission on that file.

For windows:

1. Give the permission including parent folder as same administrator.
2. Try it to do it again.

If still not work, delete the zip file and let them create again after 1st step. It will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, and after running ./gradlew build --stacktrace found out that resources folder contained Flyway migration file with name "V1.1.98__documents..sql" (double dot). Apparently this caused problems with zipping. Was typo of course.